# website with jQuery super slow firefox 4 and almost static Safari all others fine

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, safari, hover

when load website in IE, Chrome, and Orpera the jQuery on hover events work smooth and seamless

when I load website in firefox 4, I don't know older versions, perhaps, and Safari, the website is slow

in firefox, there is a lag of like 1 second after mouse has hover over item

in safari, the whole browser becomes almost static, even outside the page, the browser itself.

Could you tell me what can I change to fix this?

sample website: http://filetaxes4free.com/temporary/

aside from the jQuery being called from googel apis, this is the Jquery I wrote:

```
//set wrapper hegiht based on browser window
window.onload = setHeight;function setHeight(){ var minWidth = 0;var minHeight = 0;
    if (typeof screen.availHeight != 'undefined'){minWidth = screen.availWidth+"px"; minHeight = screen.availHeight+"px";}
    document.getElementById("leftBodyWrapper").style.minHeight = minHeight; return true;}

jQuery(document).ready( function() {
//tabs
    jQuery( "#tabs" ).tabs().tabs({  fx: { opacity: 'toggle', duration: 1000 }}).tabs('rotate', 3500, false);
//change image on hover
    jQuery("img.tabImg", jQuery('#tabs')).hover(
        function(event) {jQuery(this).attr("src", jQuery(this).attr("src").replace(".png","-active.png"));},
        function(event) { jQuery(this).attr("src", jQuery(this).attr("src").replace("-active.png",".png"));
    });
//slide menu items on hover and change color of item    
    jQuery('a', jQuery('.slideMenu')).hover(
        function(event) {jQuery(this).animate({ paddingLeft: "15px" }, 300 )
        if(jQuery(this).parent().hasClass('current'))
            jQuery(this).css("color", "#307F73"); 
        else jQuery(this).css("color", "#307F73");},
        function(event) {jQuery(this).animate({ paddingLeft: "0" }, 300 );
        if(jQuery(this).parent().hasClass('current'))
            jQuery(this).css("color", "#307F73"); 
        else jQuery(this).css("color", "#4DCCB8");});
//load PIEcss is IE
    if(navigator.appName=='Microsoft Internet Explorer'){
        if (window.PIE) {jQuery('.roundRightEI').each(function() {PIE.attach(this);});}}
});
```

Thank you,

UPDATE!!!

After deconstructing and building back this website, I realized that the CSS for Safari and Firefox is the cause of the slow down. Nothing to do with jQuery or the fonts. If I do not load the CSS, everything runs as it should.

So now, I am onto what part of the CSS is bugging the browsers. I am not sure if I should pos the CSS here.

UPDATE

OK, this is what is causing the slow down in both safari and firefox:

div#container {

```
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 200px 0 #6bcccb;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 200px 0 #6bcccb;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 200px 0 #6bcccb;
```

}

but if I do

div#container {

```
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 200px 0 #6bcccb;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 200px 0 #6bcccb;
box-shadow: 0 0 200px 0 #6bcccb;
```

}

everything is smooth (of course, I want inset shadow)

UPDATE

AND the problem WAS the long inset shadow.

200px

if I use a 5px inset shadow all is well...

I am baffled...

Comment: You just crashed my browser :)

Comment: Yep, it is slow! I also noticed your fonts (3) aren't being loaded, maybe it has something to do with it?

Comment: Wow- that sucks in Safari... I thought I'd never get that page closed.

Comment: @nosuchnick:  +1 for mentioning the fonts... it took more than 20 seconds but they eventually loaded.  But I think they're being re-downloaded over and over again for some reason.

Comment: @IberoMedia:  What is baffling?  This seems like a rendering issue.  Since each browser must draw their own shadows from scratch, they each do it differently and some will be slower than others.  You announced that this is all caused by CSS.  What about this being a combination of two things?  Perhaps redraws are happening too often?  >>  Was there anything to Benjamin's answer below about `mousemove` triggering a screen redraw every time the mouse moves a little?  Try disabling that and seeing how performance improves.

Comment: @Sparky672, I just uploaded the working site. And the only thing I had to change was the large shadow box. The code and animations appear smooth. If you take a look, would let me know if you see something wrong?  Thank you for your feedback

Comment: @IberoMedia:  You really have **A LOT** of things happening on that page... I'm not surprised you have this issue.  If it were mine, I'd reconsider that animated title.  Did you apply the shadow to the title?  The shadow, most likely, is being redrawn each time one letter changes... it would explain everything.  Also, I'm going to take a break from your issue until you [validate the page](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffiletaxes4free.com%2Ftemporary%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

Comment: @Sparky672 the problem is solved. The issue kept happening with or without the jQuery. That is why I was able to figure out that it was the CSS. The shadow was in the blue background. I should be able to have many things happening.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the Safari Developer window open and about 50% of that long loading time is spent trying to load your custom fonts.  I'd get rid of those and see if this improves.

Most of the other half of the time is spent loading your images.  Perhaps see if you can optimize those.  I'd go back to look at your graphics sizes myself but your page almost crashed my Safari last time.

Then there is some other issue triggered by (???) where the text disappears and reappears on the page.  I could not troubleshoot that for you either because the browser was all but frozen.  I suspect that you are forcing the fonts to re-download every time some mouse event happens.

Maybe post more of your code here because I'm not visiting your page again.

---

**EDIT:**

To find the offensive portion, I'd strip the page down to almost nothing and slowly add back whole pieces of working code until it chokes again.  (**EDIT:** As pointed out in another answer, start by removing the `mousemove` event.)

---

**EDIT 2:**

Please [**VALIDATE YOUR CODE**](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://filetaxes4free.com/temporary/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) before doing anything else!  I found some errors related to open HTML tags.

---

**EDIT 3:**

Nothing says you can't use both MooTools and jQuery on the same page but unless there's some compelling reason, I'd convert the code from one to the other and stick with one library... things will load faster, run better and you'll have less potential for conflict.

Comment: the CMS I use for the website requires mootools. This is why I called jQuery.noconflict(); I am editing the code to use google API's fonts, none of them really what I would want, but your suggestion about the fonts makes sense, and has been pointed out in comments below as well. Also, I will edit code to preload images, turn into objects, and then change obkject when the hover on/off (thisis the first idea that came to mind) I will keep posted once I do edits

Comment: @IberoMedia:  Using both Mootools and jQuery simultaneously is not the cause of this particular issue.  For efficiency, I just thought I'd suggest consolidating your JavaScript libraries only **if possible**.  Definitely check into that `movemouse` event that may be causing the screen to constantly redraw itself combined with the font downloading.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid the image (except for the icon in the middle). You can use CSS to create the round corner background and use the hover selector to

- change the color to a darker shade
- add a drop shadow to the icon image
- add a drop shadow to the text

That would require less work on the client side using unnecessary amount of JS.

**EDIT:**
An example or something to get you started if you decide to go with more CSS to achieve the hover affect: http://jsfiddle.net/EMvah/

Comment: I don't think his problem is all JS related.  It only took a millisecond to load... a fraction of a percent of the total page load time.

Comment: Besides, I think you got it backwards... it's easier on the client to simply load images than to use CSS to render these various effects.

Comment: In case you decide to look into a CSS route, I've updated my answer with an template to start with but it's not complete.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Gentoo with FF 4.0.1. The animations are slower than Chrome and Opera. I tried changing: div.menu position from relative to absolute. This made the animation much faster. I'm not sure what is going on with the windows folks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an `mousemove` event, which is constantly redrawing the whole stuff (big images, more than 1000px for some of them). Try to remove this event first and it should become smooth.

You cannot just redraw everything each time the mouse moves 1px! Choose a more relevant event.

Answer (score 0):

One problem i see is that the hover images are loaded after you hover on the buttons. This adds an additional delay.

I would recommend that you use image sprites, or preload the hover images with javascript.

Comment: This is good practice but it doesn't explain Safari freezing to the point of almost crashing.